# Google Maps >9.60: Can't access the layers. How to turn off/on layers?

Tags: google-maps, maps

I recently opened Google Maps and found the traffic layer to be enabled. And so I tried to turn it off by swiping from the left to open the App Drawer (aka Hamburger Menu).

Unfortunately the usual button for layers was grayed out and said that the "Layers have moved":
[image]

When I click the button it just closes the App Drawer.

I can't figure out how to access the "Satellite & traffic" or any layers. **In the new version of Google Maps, how do you turn on/off the layers (i.e. Satellite, Traffic, Topology, etc)?**

version is: 9.62.1

I tried to search for how to access the feature. But all I found was [some webpages that said the layers feature in Google-Maps was moving](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/28/google-maps-v9-60-brings-usable-picture-picture-mode-prepares-adding-personal-notes-locations-food-reviews-apk-teardown-download/)... but nothing about how to access the layers feature after it moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this change on my Samsung tablet.

I have a new button at the top right of the map, where the compass symbol used to be,  which accesses layers.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! About the button on the menu, choose where says Settings, then choose turn on.